# WSO2 Governance Registry : retrieve a Service's URL by service name?

Tags: api, service, registry, wso2

How to retrieve and call a Service's URL stored in WSO2 Governance Registry "GREG" by providing the service name; is there any simple Java method provided by the GREG API to get exactly and only the url of a service and not the whole Metadata ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouufff finally, spent the entire night to solve this problem:

```
    Registry governanceRegistry = GovernanceUtils
            .getGovernanceUserRegistry(registry, username);
    **// All governance artifacts should be loaded.
    GovernanceUtils.loadGovernanceArtifacts((UserRegistry) governanceRegistry);**
    ServiceManager manager = new ServiceManager(governanceRegistry);
```

But i stil don't know why all governance artifacts should be loaded before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Governance Artifact Search](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Governance+Artifact+Search+Sample) Sample documentation,it's demonstrating how to search governance artifacts using attributes and get the **paginated** results. You can refer [this blog](http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2013/11/jmeter-java-request-to-test.html) as well.

Comment: Please provide a short description of the solution that you linked to. Just external links is not considered an answer on stackoverflow (you've described about half a sentence already I must admit)